# If not null, get the value of the property in one LINQ line

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ and in it, I have this code which return either a string or null. The problem is if `GetUserName` return null, it will hit error. How do I write it in one line that if `GetUserName` is not null, it will return username property?

```
username = service.GetUserName(t.Id).username
```

The complete query is something like this below:

```
var members = data.Select(t => new Members
{ username = service.GetUserName(t.Id).username }).ToList();
```

If this is not possible, then I have to manually write more code to manually map the properties.

Comment: You can use [Null-conditional operators ?. ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) like `service.GetUserName(t.Id)?.username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the null conditional operator `?.` but that means then you will get members with the `username` property as `null` - I would suggest to also add a `where` after the initial select:

```
var members = data
    .Select(t => new Members{ username = service.GetUserName(t.Id)?.username })
    .Where(m => m.userName is object)
    .ToList();
```

If the constructor of the `Members` class is heavy, you can first select the userName, then filter, and then create the `Memebers` list:

```
var members = data
    .Select(t => new { service.GetUserName(t.Id)?.username }) 
    .Where(m => m.userName is object)
    .Select(t => new Members{ username = t.username })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why `m.userName is object` to perform a null check?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `x is object` is the exact opposite of `x is null`.  Read my blog post entitled [The perfect non-null test](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/the-perfect-non-null-test/) for more details.

Comment: Although != null is a cleaner way to do a null check, you can use OfType<object>() instead of the Where block

Comment: Ok, I can see the logic in that, however, it seems to me that you are sacrificing readability for an edge case that would affect a negligible number of scenarios. Furthermore, if a type overloaded `==` in such a way that `null == null` evaluated to false, then surely that should be honoured rather than bypassed?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay IMHO, once you know the logic behind it, it seems like the natural choice (though I would prefer to see `x is not null`). With I would also argue that if a type overloaded the `!=` operator in a way that `x == null` will return false even if x is null than it's implemented wrong. using `x is null` and `x is object` not only saves you from potential null reference exceptions that aren't even your fault, but also keeps your code clean. Also, `x is null` will generate a compiler error if `x` is a value type and `x is object` generates a compiler warning if `x` is a value type.

Comment: @JamalSalman see my comment to Johnathan Barclay as to why `x is object` is better than `x != null`. using `OfType<object>()` is close but not really equivalent, as it will not provide the compiler warning if the `T` is a value type.

Comment: All good points. Based on the fact that `x is object` could only be `false` when `x` is `null` I think your probably correct that it is the cleanest approach.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay To clarify - don't take my word for `x is object` being the perfect non-null test - I mean, what the # do I know, right? I would, however, claim that if the c# compiler team developer lead himself says it's "the canonical non-null test", He's probably on to something...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Null Propagation
i.e

```
 var members = data.Select(t => new Members
{ username = service.GetUserName(t.Id)?.username }).ToList();
```